# Tomcat Connection pool : tomcat-jdbc vs tomcat-dbcp, which is better?

Tags: tomcat, apache-commons-dbcp, jdbc-pool, tomcat-jdbc, tomcat-dbcp

Tomcat is using tomcat-dbcp as a default connection pool strategy, however they are also providing tomcat-jdbc as an alternative. 
Which connection pooling is better for concurrent load? 
tomcat-jdbc is having few extra parameter like jdbcInterceptors, does tomcat-dbcp have any matching parameter for Interceptors? 
Also, which one has better community support and active development ?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, i would tell tomcat-jdbc is better for concurrent loads and also interms of community support